# JavasScript function to extract href in <a>

Tags: javascript

CSS for class page_header. Header is given a 'fixed' position.

```
.page__header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Below is part of full HTML:

/* navigation bar */

```
<header class="page__header">
    <nav class="navbar__menu">
      <ul id="navbar__list">
        <li><a href="#section1">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Courses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Instructor</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
 </header>
```

/* one of the sections */

```
<section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>About</h2>
        <p>some text here</p>
        <p>some text here</p>
      </div>
</section>
```

JavaScript function that: (1) extract href target (2) extract x-coordinate & y-coordinate based on href target (3) scroll to specific section based on the coordinates.

I need help to build the part that extract href target within  tag.

```
function scroll_to_section(e) {

    if (e.target.matches("a")) {
        
        // prevent page jump straight to section when click on the URL
        e.preventDefault();

        // extract href target within <a>
        const ref = document.getElementById(e.target.href.split("#")[1]);

        // find x-coordinate & y-coordinate of the href
        const coordinate = ref.getBoundingClientRect();

        // scroll to section based on position
        window.scrollTo({
            left: coordinate.x,
            top: coordinate.y,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    }
}
```

```
const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar__list');
navbar.addEventListener("click", scroll_to_section);
```

Comment: We need example of href for this: `extract x-coordinate & y-coordinate based on href target`

Comment: Why do you even need this? Browsers follow ancor links and scroll automatically.

Comment: @Kosh but not smoothly

Comment: @mplungjan, use `scroll-behavior:smooth`. BTW, window.scrollTo is not smooth either, if scroll-behavior:smooth is not supported.

Comment: It should be supported but does not seem to do anything in my Chrome.

Comment: Please follow the [contribution guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a good question. Please do not post images of code.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this if you insist on scripting this

the parameter smooth does not seem to work so  I borrowed the CSS from the other answer which is a better answer since there is no scripting involved

```js
document.getElementById("navbar__list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName === "A") {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the normal scrolling
    const target = document.getElementById(tgt.href.split("#")[1]);
    console.log(target.dataset.nav)
    const coord = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(coord.x,coord.y)
    window.scrollTo({
      left: coord.x,
      top: coord.y,
      behavior: "smooth"
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<header class="page__header">
  <nav class="navbar__menu">
    <ul id="navbar__list">
      <li><a href="#section1">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">Courses</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Instructor</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
  <div class="landing__container">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>some text here</p>
    <p>some text here</p>
  </div>
</section>
<div style="height:1000px">
  <hr>
</div>
<section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2" class="your-active-class">
  <div class="landing__container">
    <h2>Courses</h2>
    <p>some text here</p>
    <p>some text here</p>
  </div>
</section>
<div style="height:1000px">
  <hr>
</div>
<section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3" class="your-active-class">
  <div class="landing__container">
    <h2>Instructor</h2>
    <p>some text here</p>
    <p>some text here</p>
  </div>
</section>
<div style="height:1000px">
```

Comment: I mean to create something for "let href = code;". This part is a dummy code.

Comment: Browser scrolls it without your JS. You forgot to add `preventDefault()` to hmm... prevent browser's default behavior  =)))  Then `smooth` param will work.

Comment: @Kosh DOH. Thanks. Updated. Yes I mentioned your css works without script. Perhaps OP WANTS script to implement other stuff, like colour change or something

Comment: @mplungjan, Looks like XY problem to me, anyway, you've made it.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for your advice. It works. However, I just updated CSS for ```.page_header ``` which has "fixed" position. Notice coord.y in the JS function doesn't work so well with "fixed" position in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need JavaScript to go to section =)

Example:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* this is for testing: */
p { height: 200px }
section { border: 1px solid black; margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<header class="page__header">
  <nav class="navbar__menu">
    <ul id="navbar__list">
      <li><a href="#section1">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">Courses</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Instructor</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
  <div class="landing__container">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>some text here</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2" class="your-active-class">
  <div class="landing__container">
    <h2>Courses</h2>
    <p>some text here</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3" class="your-active-class">
  <div class="landing__container">
    <h2>Instructor</h2>
    <p>some text here</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

P.S. Updated for "smooth" scroll

Comment: thanks for your help. I would like to clarify that I am aware of the using ```href="#section1" ``` to do the same thing. However, I am trying to learn to execute this in JS.